# Where to execute sdetable command in Windows?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to fire some SDE Command in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 but I am not aware where to execute the command in windows operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **execute sde commands in Windows console** or CMD. But remember that there is a new toolbox in ArcGIS, under *System Toolboxes > Data Management Tools*, called "Geodatabase Administration" that may help you to perform some SDE commands easily, like registering with a geodatabase or enable geodatabase.